# PyQt5 - how to check if UI window is opened

Tags: python, pyqt5

Is there a function that checks if UI window is still opened.
I would like to end a process if the UI is closed. Maybe something similar to `isActiveWindow()`.

Comment: maybe `isVisible()`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: If you post it as an answer I can accept it, since you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the `isHidden()` method

Comment: `isHidden()` always returns False

Comment: `isHidden()` returns false depending on the situation, as `isHidden()` is not always the opposite of `isVisible()`. See the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#isHidden).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29468734)

Comment: @slideshowp2: Why not? It may not be a _correct_ or _useful_ answer—I’m not qualified to judge—but that’s what voting is for ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)).